# How to develop Augmented Reality application for Android

Tags: android, air, flash-cs5, augmented-reality

I would like to develop an augmented reality application on a HTC Nexus One mobile phone for android using Flash Professional CS5 and Adobe AIR 2.5.

I found a couple of online sources showing how to develop AR application using webcam and Flash and i have found it very useful to follow and understand the basics of AR.

For example:

1. Augmented Reality using webcam and Flash
   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/augmented_reality.html
2. Introduction to Augmented Reality
   http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=105

I have also watched other videos regarding AIR for Android Applications from gotoandlearn website and i did all of the successfully such as:

1. Air for Android – Part 1
2. Air for Android – Part 2
3. Publishing AIR for Android Applications
4. AIR for Android GPU Acceleration
5. Introduction to Augmented Reality

However, i didn't manage to get it work on my android phone (doing nothing and run very slow).

I would like to ask a few questions on the following:

1) To develop an Augmented Reality application on android, is this done using the same method as the one's above?

2) Do I need to use any other software other than those that is showing on the video and adobe air 2.5?

3) Do you know of any other sources/reading material that are relevant and may be of help?

Thank you

Comment: see this fruitful thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039334/communication-between-two-apps-using-emulator-as-server-and-client

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Augmented Reality (AR) is a generic term for an interactive 3D environment that blends with our physical reality, usually through a webcam, or in this case, a phone camera.

1. You can develop AR apps for Android with nothing more than the Android SDK, since it provides API for interacting with the camera, and it supports OpenGL for 3D graphics.
   Since AR usually involves complex algorithms of image recognition, it's not a trivial task, so leveraging existing tools is definitely a good option.
2. Since using Adobe AIR and Flash, is actually running the Flash virtual machine over the Dalvik virtual machine, you might experience performance issues for such a CPU intensive task such as AR.
3. If using other tools is also an option for you, you can check out [Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK](http://developer.qualcomm.com/ar)

Comment: I know this is an old question. But i would like to ask; Wouldn't creating it in adobe air make it easier to do it cross platform for android and ios?

Comment: @AbdullahGheith, yes that's correct; Lior's #2 means that even though it may be easier to develop an Air app, it is not worth making the AR slow just because it's easier. I would recommend trying both ways since we don't have any info about their performances (2/3). And please report back on your results.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a cool open-source project that might get you on your way:
http://code.google.com/p/andar/

and: https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality

Regards,
Yusuf

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty exist in the market.

After I googled came to know of 3 sdk's which are find to go.

```
> Vuforia - But it's pricing and expensive 
> ARToolkit - Fine to go and flexible to use it 
> Wikitude - Good to go and sdk should be still stable I guess.
```

So In my point of view lets start with ARToolkit and I am fresh in to AR development.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android_augmented-reality/
You can have a look at this. Provides brief intro about the key components of developing an AR app.

Answer (score 1):

When you decide to develop an AR application, you should begin with choosing an Augmented Reality framework. First, make a list of features that you expect to find in the appropriate SDK: types of recognized images, geolocation elements, animation or something else. Then consider what type of license you can afford. After all, compare different AR frameworks on the base of chosen features.

Here is a prominent review that can be helpful with the choice of Augmented Reality SDK: http://cases.azoft.com/top-5-tools-creating-augmented-reality-apps/