# augmented reality -- Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am new and blank to augmented reality framework for android. Can anyone guide me on how to integrate this with android applications. And any other framework for augmented reality which could be used to our application. please guide me.

Comment: Augmented reality is a really broad topic, and telling you how to integrate every framework in a single answer is near impossible. Try researching a bit and coming up with a more specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below link

[**AndAR - Android Augmented Reality**](https://code.google.com/p/andar/)

can be a good start point.

Augmented Reality (AR) is a generic term for an interactive 3D environment that blends with our physical reality, usually through a webcam, or in this case, a phone camera.

And also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797000/1441666