# android augmented reality image targets

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, augmented-assignment

I am planning to develop an augmented reality application for Android phone. Does anyone know if there is any existing framework(in java programming langueage) for augmented reality which could be used for such applications?

Thanks.

Comment: will you please explain a bit,what is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There're already several answered questions related to AR development.
For instance [augmented reality framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework?rq=1)
and [augmented reality -- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354183/augmented-reality-android?rq=1)

Comment: so it should be a comment.:-)

Comment: You are right. But I can't add comments to original question due to lack of reputation.